# MathJax is displaying 'Unknown node type: apply'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mathjax, mathml

I am trying to display MathML in chrome by using MathJax. I managed to do it till now from this repo 'https://github.com/pmq20/mathjax-rails' but not all math formulas are being shown. Instead I am getting this: `Unknown node type: apply` and one time `Unknown node type: ci`. I tried different configuration files such as `'Accessible-full.js'` or `'MML_HTMLorMML-full.js'` but I get the same result. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You are looking for https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/mathml.html#content-mathml

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I tried putting that in the configuration file but no luck. It doesn't work either.

Comment: You'll need to post a reproducible sample using the snippet functionality here on SO if you want to get more help.